# Custom Check style in JFace CheckboxTreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I can implement JFace CheckboxTreeViewer like following with check style inside the checkbox

[image]

But I want to get checkbox with cross (x) style upon selection. Can I implement following style?

i.e

[image]

Comment: The check boxes are drawn by the native control that SWT uses and can't be changed. You would have to write your own label provider using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` (or one of its many subclasses) and implement the check box behaviour yourself.

Comment: @greg-449 can we use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` along with `CheckboxTreeViewer` ?

Comment: Looking through my code I do have something using `StyledCellLabelProvider` (which extends OwnerDrawLabelProvider) on columns in a checkbox table, but there is no way to set this up for the checkbox column.